# how to Dynamically generate JSON in a loop with Js?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop, pebble-watch

I'm making a project with [PebbleJS](http://pebble.github.io/pebblejs/).

i'm a noob and i'm learning little by little..so after recieving a JSON from a webpage and put all the data in localStorage objects, i want to put my variables in a UI.Menu Window, which is basically a JSON variable as you can see in example below:

```
var main = new UI.Menu({
sections: [{
  items: [
  {
    title: 'street name a',
    subtitle: 'ID 1121'
  }, {
    title: 'street name b',
    subtitle: 'ID 1431'
  }, {
    title: 'street name c',
    subtitle: 'ID 1907'
  },{
    title: 'street name d',
    subtitle: 'ID 1002'
  },{
    title: 'street name e',
    subtitle: 'ID 1330'
  },

        ]
}]
});
```

i tried to make a loop cycle inside but gives me error...(pseudocode)

```
for (var x=0;x<10;x++)
  {
    title: localStorage.title+x,
    subtitle: 'ID '+localStorage.title+x
  }
```

i need to make this with no jQuery or other JS Frameworks, only pure javascript...

Comment: You might want to look in to a [js forEach() statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This will allow you to iterate over your entire JSON object without having to know how long it is. This way you can iterate over the localstorage object, and continue to push onto a blank object/array that you defined, following that you should have an object you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you question correctly, you want to create the data-structure from your first code example through a loop.

the data structure is a object with some properties and sub-objects like arrays. the structure just defines objects in your code. there is no json involved.

json is a subset of javascript which is used to interchange data-structures. it consists of plain text files with just javascript object declarations and is usually parsed to create a data-structure in memory. by declaring your data-structure in code there is no need to use an additional json-parsing step.

to setup the initial structure as above you would do:

```
var data = {
    sections: [
        {
            items: []
        }
    ]
}
```

than you would get the items array:

```
var items = data.sections[0].items
```

to this array you can add the items with your loop:

```
for ( var x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
    var item = {
      title: localStorage.title + x,
      subtitle: 'ID ' + localStorage.title + x
    };

    items.push(item);
}
```

now you can build your UI.Menu with the data-object.

```
var main = new UI.Menu(data)
```

Comment: yes, you're supposing right!!!
that's exactly what i'm trying to do! thank you for helping me understand what i need to do and sorry if  i wasn't clear in the question!
oh i have another one for you @dreamlab, i tried your solution out of the box and its a no-go(no menu items displayed). Surely i need to retouch things, is there a way i could test in, like, jsfiddle? pebble compiler doesnt throw anything related to menu.

Comment: you can test the above code without the last line in jsfiddle. like here: http://jsfiddle.net/tedgp4fk/. in the console you can check if the data-structure you pass to UI.Menu is correct. i don't know jspebble. but if you have a minimal setup to display a menu i can look at it and probably help.